# Proving minimum number of chairs is $567$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

[image: Jayant]

**Hints only please!**

I am trying to figure this out somehow. A row can have as many girls, and a column can have as many boys.

Proof by contradiction seems like a good technique, but I am not sure how much it would help here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Thanks for tagging "diophantine-equations," it sparked up an idea =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $r$ be the number of rows and $c$ be the number of columns. There are $14r$ boys and $10c$ girls along with $3$ empty seats. There are $rc$ seats in all. Thus, $14r+10c+3=rc$.

Subtracting $14r+3$ from both sides shows us that $10c=(c-14)r-3$ or $10c \equiv -3 \pmod r$.

Subtracting $10c+3$ from both sides shows us that $14r=(r-10)c-3$ or $14r \equiv -3 \pmod c$.

Not sure if this will lead you to the solution, but hopefully, these equations help!

Comment: The equation of the first paragraph is very useful.

Comment: Nicely done. Clear thinking. +1

Comment: Absolutely brilliant along with @AndréNicolas's hint. In the end, you get, Diophantine, $(R-10)(C-14) = 143$, which yield $(R, C) = (23, 25), (21, 27)$. Using the second case, we get $R*C = 21*27 = 567$.

Comment: There are also the solutions $R-10=1$, $C-14=143$ and the other way around, but these give bigger answers.